# web - button.onclick = func(); vs <button onclick = "func()"?

Tags: javascript, html, web, onclick

I'm new to javascript and I'm not using jQuery.

I'm trying to make my function `btnHandle()` run when I click the button.

However, I found that

```
btn.onclick = btnHandle();
```

is different from

```
<button id="sort-btn" onclick="btnHandle()">submit</button>
```

When I use `btn.onclick = btnHandle();`, the `btnHandle()` function is executed when I refresh the code **without clicking the button**.

I want the function be executed only when the button clicked.

`<button id="sort-btn" onclick="btnHandle()">submit</button>` works as I want.

Why the previous one not working well? Why the `onclick` event is fired the the page is loaded?

```
    <button id="sort-btn" onclick="btnHandle()">submit</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function btnHandle() {
        var aqiData = getData();
        aqiData = sortAqiData(aqiData);
        render(aqiData);
    }


    function init() {
        var btn = document.getElementById("sort-btn");
    //        btn.onclick = btnHandle();
    }

    init();
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kevin points out, the function is executing immediately because you have parentheses after it.

However, both of these approaches are outdated now. You should use `addEventListener`:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', btnHandle);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
btn.onclick = btnHandle;
```

without parenthesis

btnHandle references the function while
btnHandle() executes the function